# Spring boot (.2.3.0.RELEASE) with bucket4j rate limit not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to use limit rate API for a Spring Boot Rest application, with bucket4j based on the following [online resource](https://github.com/MarcGiffing/bucket4j-spring-boot-starter)

Please find my configuration below:

Below is maven dependency added to use 4bucketj:

```
...
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.giffing.bucket4j.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
            <artifactId>bucket4j-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
..
```

Below is my application.yml config:

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  cache:
    jcache:
      config: classpath:ehcache.xml
bucket4j:
  enabled: true
  filters:
    - cache-name: buckets
      url: .*
      http-response-body: "{ \"status\": 429, \"error\": \"Too Many Requests\", \"message\": \"You have exhausted your API Request Quota\" }"
      rate-limits:
        - bandwidths:
            - capacity: 2
              time: 1
              unit: minutes
```

Below I have added ehcache.xml in path src/main/resources/:

```
<config xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:jsr107="http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-107-ext-3.0.xsd">
    <cache alias="buckets">
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">3600</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <heap unit="entries">1000000</heap>
        <jsr107:mbeans enable-statistics="true"/>
    </cache>
```

Finally, I have added `@EnableCaching`in a config class which is being loaded when spring starts.

Based on the config in the application.yml file the API should not accept more than 2 request in one minute and if it is more that two requests, an error should be triggered as stated (`http-response-body`) in application.yml.

I have deployed the application on my PC and with Postman tool I am able to hit a Rest API more than 10 times within one minute with no error message.

Can anyone please advise why the error message is not triggered, since it should allow only 2 requests and I am sending 10 instead?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by following [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bucket4j) from the point 6 onwards, but the only difference i can spot with your implementation is the caching system, so i can guess the problem lies there.